# Creating a two-dimensional array of fixed-length strings (character arrays)

Tags: c, arrays, char

So I've been trying to create an object in C that would essentially be two columns of empty char arrays. Its contents would resemble

```
char * strings[3][2]
{
  {"thing1", "value1"}
  {"thing2", "value2"}
  {"thing3", "value3"}
}
```

...except the actual char *s would be empty arrays with fixed length, rather than initialized strings, i.e. each string would actually be something like "char string[6]".

I've been searching for some time but I'm coming up dry. Would anyone happen to know the syntax for creating such an object?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe like this:

```
typedef char sixchars[7];

sixchars strings[3][2] = { { "thing1", "value1" }
                         , { "thing2", "value2" }
                         , { "thing3", "value3" }
                         };
```

Comment: @RobertHarvey: There are six lights.

Comment: This also appears to be working: For a two-dimensional array of character arrays of length 20, with 3 rows and 2 columns: `char (myarray[3][2])[20]`.

Comment: @EricFields: Sure, you don't need the typedef. I just put it in there for readability.